# Error C2664 in hid_device.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stderr, hid, c2664

```
std::string get_path( void ) { return m_devicePath; }
```

Debug output:

> hid_device.h(37) : error C2664: >'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::>_Has_debug_it)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned long' to >'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::_Has_debug_it'
>          with
>          [
>              _Elem=char,
>              _Traits=std::char_traits,
>              _Ax=std::allocator
>          ]
>          Constructor for struct 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::_Has_debug_it' is declared 'explicit'
>          with
>          [
>              _Elem=char,
>              _Traits=std::char_traits,
>              _Ax=std::allocator
>          ]

Comment: What is `m_devicePath`? Is it really an `unsigned long` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Option 1:

Wrong includes. You should have `#include <string>`, not `#include <string.h>` or any other variation at the top of the file.

- Option 2:

`m_devicePath` is an `unsigned long` (doubt that) and can't be directly converted to `std::string`.

Use `std::to_string()` **(C++11)**:

```
std::string get_path( void ) { return std::to_string(m_devicePath); }
```

or a `stringstream` **(C++03)** to convert the `unsigned long` to a `std::string`:

```
std::string get_path( void ) { 
     std::stringstream ss;
     ss << m_devicePath;
     return ss.str(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's option 2 since I have the former include statement at the top. Now it's complaining that to_string is not a member of std.

Comment: @sudonym that means you don't have a C++11 compiler. Use the second option instead (with `#include <sstream>`).